Solar PV installation with DC heater and ideal diode
I want to build a small off-grid PV system (<1kWp, pure DC) with simple components. The majority of the generated power during the day should go to a DC heating element, the systems main purpose.  I also want the system battery to be (priority) charged to drive various small things like a fan and some LED Lights over night.

I do not want to drive the heater with "precious" energy stored in the battery -- just what is available during the day after charging it. I know that MPPT controllers can work without a battery with pure resistive loads, but I still need a source of power during the night.
I figure something like an ideal diode would allow the MPPT to sense the battery voltage while no current is allowed to drain back at night.
When the heater is active all current will flow through it since it has a very low resistance compared to the battery. To allow priority charging I could enable the heater only after the battery is fully charged.
Would that work? Am I missing something easier, more obvious? See also and.

Whether this works depends on how intelligent the MPPT controller is. The less intelligent it is, the better.
The problem in this case is that with minimal power production, such as when you get only few watts before the sun sets, the voltage at the MPPT controller output is very small, since P = U^2/R or slightly modifying the equation, U = sqrt(P*R). Your MPPT controller has to be able to work down to 0 volts, without the 0-volt operation damaging the power electronics, and without the MPPT controller declaring your battery dead. A less intelligent MPPT controller might not care, a more intelligent controller might declare your battery permanently dead and refuse to work afterwards, at about the first sunset.
Your MPPT controller also can't have any intelligent battery sensing algorithms. It is possible that an intelligent MPPT controller might sometimes stop charging for a split second to check if the battery is still there, and if it sees the battery is not there (by voltage reducing to zero), throw an error code and refuse to work until you manually ensure the battery is well-connected.
Also, the during each night, the power to the MPPT controller will be lost. It requires maybe a watt to operate. It can get that watt only from the solar panels due to the ideal diode, not from the battery. During each night, the panels can't produce even that single watt. So the MPPT controller has to be able to lose power, and then reconnect the power panels first. I suspect most MPPT controllers have been designed to work in a manner where the battery is reconnected first and the panels only after that. Your MPPT controller has to work in exactly the opposite way. However, with the advent of LiFePO4 batteries, we have batteries that have a deep discharge protection circuit, and those require "waking up" by the MPPT controller if they are deep discharged. So I suspect a good MPPT controller designed for LiFePO4 supports that wakeup, and the wakeup happens by the MPPT controller supplying power to the battery from the panels despite the fact that the battery voltage is zero.
My advice: try it, it's the simplest way to make this. Maybe it'll work. Maybe it won't.
If it doesn't work, then you have an alternative: remove the ideal diode and connect the heater to the battery via a relay or a logic level power MOSFET. Add a cheap Arduino or a Raspberry Pi (or maybe an analog operational amplifier circuit, but then you need to prevent oscillation with a time delay using an RC circuit and I believe oscillation prevention would be simplest using Arduino or Raspberry Pi). Sense the current direction with something like ACS712 if 30 amperes is enough for you (if not, maybe there are solutions for higher currents like a shunt but a high-current shunt is less precise). Then control that relay or MOSFET by the current direction: if the battery would be discharged, turn that relay or power MOSFET off.
So essentially this would be splitting the ideal diode into two. One is a current sensor (you are only interested in the current direction). Another is a power MOSFET/relay. The current sensor would be in exactly the same position as the ideal diode is now. The MOSFET/relay switch would however be between the heater and the wires to the battery and MPPT controller. So this split approach would let the MPPT controller always see the battery, and would only disconnect the power from the heater when the current direction would go into discharge.
However, a drawback of this split approach is that the heater would be always fully on at full voltage or fully off. It won't produce heat at half or quarter of the power if the sun is going down or it's cloudy. So it will oscillate at lower power levels, and you need to prevent too fast oscillation. Maybe you could think of the oscillation as PWM modulating it to have the desired power level.
